# Find the potential difference given the function of electric field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage

I have the following problem:

Suppose that, as a function of x, an electric field has an x component

$E_x=6x^2y$

where the electric field is measured in volts per meter and the distances are measured in meters. Find the potential difference between the origin and the point x=3 on the x axis.

I have done the following:

$x=0\;\;\; E_{x0}=0\;\;\; V_0=0\\
  x=3\;\;\; E_{x3}=54y\\~\\
  V=-\int_{0}^{3}E\ dl\cos0=-\int_{0}^{3}E_{x3}dx=-\int_{0}^{3}54ydx=-54y[x]_0^3=-54y*3=-162y$

However, the answer in the book says that the potential difference is $0V$. Should I assume that there is no change in electric field across y-axis, hence y=0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are moving along the x-axis then $y=0$ and so $E_{\rm x}=0$.
This means that the potential along the x-axis is a constant and so the potential difference between any two points on the x-axis is zero.